# Postgresql container in kubernetes doesn’t use POSTGRES_PASSWORD env

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, deployment

I’ve got a problem with creating container with postgresql image. Down below is yaml. I have successfully created container with this configuration and I can enter this DB, BUT env POSTGRES_PASSWORD doesn’t work. It means it is possible to enter this Database with NO Password.

Why so? There are a lot of tutorials, but all containers, created using these tutorials, don’t implement Password info

In details I’m trying something like this:

```
kubectl exec [POD_NAME] – psql -h localhost -U user --password -p 5432 postgres
```

And no need to enter password, but i want to enter the Database ONLY with Password

I successfully create container with configuration below and I can enter this DB, BUT env POSTGRES_PASSWORD doesn’t work. It means it is possible to enter this Database with NO Password.
But I set password by using:

```
- name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  value: user
```

Here are my yaml

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1    
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: example-postgres
      labels:
        app: example-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
      tier: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
        tier: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: postgres
          name: postgres
          env:

            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres

            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: user

            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: user

            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-postgres
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: example-app
    tier: postgres
```

How to make container to check password before enter the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get some more details about the POSTGRES_PASSWORD variable:

> POSTGRES_PASSWORD

> This environment variable is required for you to use the PostgreSQL image. It must not be empty or undefined. This environment variable sets the superuser password for PostgreSQL. The default superuser is defined by the POSTGRES_USER environment variable.

> Note 1: **The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost (inside the same container).** However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container.

> Note 2: This variable defines the superuser password in the PostgreSQL instance, as set by the initdb script during initial container startup. It has no effect on the PGPASSWORD environment variable that may be used by the psql client at runtime, as described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-envars.html. PGPASSWORD, if used, will be specified as a separate environment variable.

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

I think you have to edit the DB to change the setting.

Also try to see this link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126176